# Can I see result of 2 requests in one listener?

Tags: performance, jmeter, response, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

In Jmeter I have 2 requests:

- first request will access the token
- second will process the token

In result I can see time of request and response from Request 1 and from Request 2.

Is it possible to see result of two requests together in Jmeter. E.g.

```
Request 1 : 5ms  
Request 2 : 3ms
total     : 8ms
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Transaction controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to achieve this: add both requests *under* transaction controller, like this:

[image]

The Transaction Controller will report time for both Request 1 and 2 together:

[image]